# Bluetooth device discovery in Android -- startDiscovery()

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, android-adapter, android-context

**Goal:** Build an Android app that discovers the names and addresses of BT devices within range and submits their values to a webservice. BT devices have not been previously bonded to the host device, I just want to poll everything as I walk about.

What I've done:

1. Pored over documentation.
2. Implemented a local instance of the host device's BT adapter.
3. Implemented a notification to enable BT if it isn't enabled.
4. Registered Broadcast Receivers and Intents to parse the `ACTION_FOUNDs` coming off of **startDiscovery()**.
5. Registered **BLUETOOTH** and **BLUETOOTH_ADMIN** permissions in the manifest.

Things work (as tested with incremental console logging) up until `startDiscovery()`.

**Frustration:**

- **startDiscovery()** -- I suspect I am passing this in the wrong context. What context does this method need to be placed within to function properly?

If you have been able to get this method working, I would very much appreciate your wisdom.

**UPDATE** - here's a stripped down simplified version of the code that is causing me grief; this simplification recapitulates my error. This code runs, it throws no `cat.log` errors or other errors, it simply doesn't give any output.

```
package aqu.bttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BT2Activity extends Activity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBTA;
private SingBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //register local BT adapter
    mBTA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    //check to see if there is BT on the Android device at all
    if (mBTA == null){
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Bluetooth on this handset", duration).show();
    }
    //let's make the user enable BT if it isn't already
    if (!mBTA.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBT, 0xDEADBEEF);
    }
    //cancel any prior BT device discovery
    if (mBTA.isDiscovering()){
        mBTA.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    //re-start discovery
    mBTA.startDiscovery();

    //let's make a broadcast receiver to register our things
    mReceiver = new SingBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
}

private class SingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction(); //may need to chain this to a recognizing function
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a Toast
            String derp = device.getName() + " - " + device.getAddress();
            Toast.makeText(context, derp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It would help to know the error you are getting... or at least what exactly is leading you to believe that `startDiscovery()` is functioning incorrectly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What context does this method need to be placed within to function properly.

To put it simply, you should use `startDiscovery()` when you want your application to discover local Bluetooth devices... for instance, if you wanted to implement a `ListActivity` that scans and dynamically adds nearby Bluetooth devices to a `ListView` (see [`DeviceListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.html)).

Your usage of the `startDiscovery()` method should look something like this:

1. Define a class variable representing the local Bluetooth adapter.

   ```
   BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
   ```
2. Check to see if your device is already "discovering". If it is, then cancel discovery.

   ```
   if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
       mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
   }
   ```
3. Immediately after checking (and possibly canceling) discovery-mode, start discovery by calling,

   ```
   mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
   ```
4. Be very careful in general about accidentally leaving your device in discovery-mode. Performing device discovery is a heavy procedure for the Bluetooth adapter and will consume a lot of its resources. For instance, you want to make sure you check/cancel discovery prior to attempting to make a connection. You most likely want to cancel discovery in your `onDestroy` method too.

Let me know if this helped... and if you are still having trouble, update your answer with your logcat output and/or any error messages you are getting, and maybe I can help you out a bit more.

Comment: That helped. Also, passing results to an ArrayAdapter instead of a Toast definitely also helped.

Comment: is there any way to keep scanning continuous in BG service without put Timer...any system level API.

Comment: @Shubh I don't think so. The reason why this restriction is put in place is to ensure that applications don't abuse `Bluetooth` by continuously scanning in the background.

Comment: Very old... I am trying to do the same, but what could be the error ?- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987424/java-lang-securityexception-while-context-registerreceiver-in-uiautomator-ins